# Unable to compile Firefox OS

Tags: compilation, firefox-os

Sorry about the vagueness of the question title, but I've been having problems compiling Firefox OS and am unsure where to turn (I know there's Bugzilla but I'm not sure if what I'm experiencing is a bug or not)

Basically, I've been trying to compile the latest Firefox OS from source using the [official instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building). I'm trying to build a system that supports the languages `en-GB`, `en-US` and `tr` (with `en-GB` as the default). My `.userconfig` is as follows:

```
export MAKE=
export CC=gcc-4.6
export CXX=g++-4.6

VARIANT=user

# GAIA l10n
export GAIA_DEFAULT_LOCALE="en-GB"
export LOCALE_BASEDIR="$PWD/locales"
export LOCALES_FILE="$PWD/locales/languages_some.json"
export GAIA_KEYBOARD_LAYOUTS="en,tr"

# Gecko l10n
export L10NBASEDIR=$PWD/gecko-locales
export MOZ_CHROME_MULTILOCALE="en-GB tr"
export PATH="$PATH:$PWD/compare-locales/scripts"
export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/compare-locales/lib"
```

The contents of `languages_some.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "en-GB"     : "English (GB)",
  "en-US"     : "English (US)",
  "tr"        : "Türkçe"
}
```

`compare_locales` contains an unmodified clone of [this repo](http://hg.mozilla.org/build/compare-locales), and `gecko-locales` contains clones of [en-GB](http://hg.mozilla.org/l10n-central/en-GB) and [tr](http://hg.mozilla.org/l10n-central/tr) locales from the official repository (there is no 'en' or 'en-US' repository).

Now, I'm not 100% sure where the error is. I have tried searching Google for any suspect lines, but nothing has come up.

I have posted full output as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ukch/64dcb23202793acba4ca). Suspect lines as far as I can tell (this is my first time compiling either Firefox or a mobile phone OS) are:

```
2015-03-16 16:43:12: stackwalker.cc:125: INFO: Couldn't load symbols for: |
2015-03-16 16:43:12: basic_code_modules.cc:88: INFO: No module at 0x2ab95ac94aa0
```

(then followed by a lot of 'No module at ...' errors)

also

```
System JS : ERROR file:///opt/src/B2G/gaia/b2g_sdk/34.0a1-2014-08-12-04-02-01/b2g/components/nsHandlerService.js:120 - NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]
```

This error is repeated a fair few times throughout the code, but I can't tell if it's harmless or if it's stopping the build.

There's also a bunch of lines about missing translations, but I imagine they're just harmless. I have tried to cut them down as much as possible (by adding the missing translations) but the problem persists.

Oh yes, and in case someone asks, I have been running with my phone plugged in, and it is visible on `adb devices`. I have also tried removing the `out` and `backup-inari` directories.

System specs, PC:

- Debian Sid, mostly up-to-date, but running with an old version of `make` (build refuses to run on any version newer than 3.8)
- GCC 4.6 and 4.9. `export CC=gcc-4.6` set in `.userconfig`
- G++ 4.6 and 4.9. `export CXX=g++-4.6` set in `.userconfig`

Phone:

- Original ZTE Open. This originally came with FFOS 1.0, but I have since upgraded to 1.1 by [flashing the official ROM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Phone_guide/ZTE_OPEN).

Comment: It could be a good idea to retry and tell if you're still having the problem. I remember I had many problem compiling ffos a year ago and now it seems to work without much problems.